# Cannot access specific websites Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, vpn

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.10 on my Laptop today, and I cannot access some specific websites, that I could when I had Windows on my Laptop. The only way for me to access these websites is by using a VPN. And no this has nothing to do with my ISP, because like a said on the same laptop and network I was able to access those websites. These websites are pretty random from what I could observe (live.com for example).

How should I deal with this issue?

Comment: What does `nslookup live.com` return? What about `tracepath -n live.com`

Comment: Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: live.com
Address: 65.55.206.154

Whereas the tracepath ends up in no reply after following two or three IP addresses

Comment: Try to change DNS for google ones: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: @apex39 DNS is not at issue it's already resolving to correct ip. everything looks fine on your end, for some reason something is dropping it down the line from your PC. So your ISP. Did you have a proxy set up on your Windows box?